# How to rename identical values in a column within R?

Tags: r, indexing, rename, gsub

Say a data set:

```
a <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103)
b <- c("M","M","P","P","M","M")
dt <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
dt

    a b
1 101 M
2 101 M
3 102 P
4 102 P
5 103 M
6 103 M
```

Column a is **subject_ID**, and column b is **subject_name**. I want to uniquely rename subject ID 101 to M1, and 103 to M2.

Is there a way to do this by indexing?

This does not work.

```
dt.try1 <- gsub("M","M1",dt[1:2,c(2)])
dt.try1
[1] "M1" "M1"
```

This is what would be ideal result:

```
    a  b
1 101  M
2 101  M
3 102  P
4 102  P
5 103 M2
6 103 M2
```

Why does not this work?

Comment: You say you want to rename the subject Id, but the difference in your results is in subject name.

Comment: `as.data.frame(cbind(a, b))` is a wrong way to create a dataframe. If `a` and `b` are variables with different types, `cbind()` will coerce them into identical types. Use `data.frame(a, b)` instead.

Comment: Just as a matter of clarity,  may I recommend a different scheme?  map "101 M" to "101 M1" ,  "103 M" to "103 M3"  and even when there's only one "P" (so far!!!!), map "102 P" to "102 P2"  .   You will thank me when you get up to a few dozen values  :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample data.

```r
a <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103)
b <- c("M","M","P","P","M","M")
dt <- data.frame(a, b)
```

FYI, never use `data.frame(cbind(..))` to create a frame: in this case, since at least one of the vectors is `character`, they will all be `character` since `cbind` by default creates matrices (which are limited to one class, unlike frames). It's always better here to use `data.frame(..)` directly.

*Note:* for clarity, your "ideal output" shows `M,M,P,P,M2,M2`, but your previous code block trying to change the first two to `M1`. I'm basing my code on the assumption that you need the first two to be `M1` instead of just `M`. (For that, akrun's answer is correct, though this metholodogy could be adjusted.)

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
  distinct(a, b) %>%
  group_by(b) %>%
  mutate(b = if (n() > 1) paste0(b, row_number()) else b) %>%
  left_join(dt, ., by = "a", suffix = c(".x", "")) %>%
  select(-b.x)
#     a  b
# 1 101 M1
# 2 101 M1
# 3 102  P
# 4 102  P
# 5 103 M2
# 6 103 M2
```

## base R

```r
dt2 <- unique(dt[, c("a", "b")])
dt2$b <- ave(dt2$b, dt2$b, FUN = function(z) if (length(z) > 1) paste0(z, seq_along(z)) else z)
dt2
#     a  b
# 1 101 M1
# 3 102  P
# 5 103 M2
merge(subset(dt, select = -b), dt2, by = "a")
#     a  b
# 1 101 M1
# 2 101 M1
# 3 102  P
# 4 102  P
# 5 103 M2
# 6 103 M2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
within(dt, b[b == 'M'] <- paste0('M', with(rle(a[b == 'M']), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))))
```

Output:

```
    a  b
1 101 M1
2 101 M1
3 102  P
4 102  P
5 103 M2
6 103 M2
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `rle/inverse.rle` from `base R`

```
dt$b <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(dt$b), values <- make.unique(values, sep = "")))
```

-output

```
> dt
    a  b
1 101  M
2 101  M
3 102  P
4 102  P
5 103 M1
6 103 M1
```

---

Or using `rle` in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dt %>% 
  mutate(b = inverse.rle(within.list(rle(b), 
  values <- str_replace_all(make.unique(values, sep = ""),  
       "(\\d+)", function(x) as.numeric(x) + 1) )))
```

-output

```
    a  b
1 101  M
2 101  M
3 102  P
4 102  P
5 103 M2
6 103 M2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat `a` as a factor and then check for `levels(a) > 1`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  group_by(b) |> 
  mutate(n_lvl = length(levels(factor(a))),
         b = paste0(b, ifelse(n_lvl > 1, as.integer(factor(a)), ""))) |> 
  select(-n_lvl)

# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   b [3]
      a b    
  <dbl> <chr>
1   101 M1   
2   101 M1   
3   102 P    
4   102 P    
5   103 M2   
6   103 M2
```

Data from @r2evans

```
a <- c(101,101,102,102,103,103)
b <- c("M","M","P","P","M","M")
df <- tibble(a, b)
```